# Printig raw data EPL using Mono C#

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#, epl

I need to print RAW DATA to a Zebra Label Printer using Mono under Ubuntu 10.04+

Iv tried GTk-sharp print but i couldn't find a way to set RAW data parameter and the outupt was the EPL program itself.

In windows this is achieved using Winspool.drv

thanks

Comment: what exactly do you do on windows?

Answer (score 0):

The [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/) driver has support for Zebra printers. [Here is a Zebra White paper on how to install and use cups for sending ZPL/EPL to the printer from linux](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO2554&actp=LIST_POPULAR)